# Fresh Pixel image freezes at startup

Tags: raspbian-jessie, pixel

I've got a Raspberry Pi 3, powered with an official Raspberry Pi power supply.

I had Jessie installed on it, but hadn't updated in a while. I tried to do an apt update which took about an hour, and ended up with the Pi freezing with a black screen. I pulled the power and rebooted. It started and displayed the Pixel desktop, with the usual "click here to open applications menu" indicator, but the mouse and keyboard are not responsive. The clock changes though.

Figuring I broke something interrupting the update, I burned the 2017-03-02 Raspbian image to an SD card, and tried again.

It does exactly the same - boots but then freezes after login.

Mouse and keyboard worked until today.

[EDIT] During boot it displays "Failed to insert module 'ipv6'
and also "[FAILED] Failed to start Load Kernel Modules."

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you corrupted your SD card?  Did you fully reformat it?

Comment: Thanks - it's a brand new image so there's no "format", the whole disk image is transferred to the card. Others have suggested it may be a hardware issue so I'm waiting to get access to another Pi and will try the card in that.

Comment: I'm not positive on this, but I don't think reimagining always fixes corruption.  I'm fairly certain that reformatting does.  Personally, I'd give reformatting a shot.